# Trying to align text in center of rectangle while drawing freeText annotation but text goes in top left corner

Tags: itext

I am trying to free text Annotation string align in center of rectangle  but always set in top left corner

```
PdfContentByte pcb = stamper.getOverContent(page);
PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createFreeText(stamper.getWriter(), rectangle, "Mayank Pandey", pcb);
annotation.put(PdfName.Q, new PdfNumber(PdfFormField.Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE));
```

Text showing left top corner in pdf:

[image: Text showing left top corner in pdf]

Answer (score 0):

You set

```
annotation.put(PdfName.Q, new PdfNumber(PdfFormField.Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE));
```

The constant `Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE` is defined as

```
/**
 * A possible value for vertical alignment.
 */
public static final int ALIGN_MIDDLE = 5;
```

But the value of **Q** in free text annotations is specified as:

> **Q**
>   integer
>   *(Optional; PDF 1.4)* A code specifying the form of *quadding* (justification) that shall be used in displaying the annotation’s text:
>   
>   0 Left-justified
>   
>   1 Centered
>   
>   2 Right-justified
>   
>   Default value: 0 (left-justified).

Thus, value `5` you used is not a valid **Q**uadding value at all!

Furthermore, **FreeText** **Q**uadding does not even support what you want to achieve, to *align in center of rectangle*, it only allows to select horizontal alignment, not vertical alignment.

For your objective, therefore, you'll have to use a custom appearance (which takes precedence if present).

Comment: Thanks for clarification.